# Python 3.3.3 time.sleep() error

Tags: python, time, sleep

I'm getting the following error:

```
The error:"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jamie\Desktop\Python\ATM.py", line 8, in <module>
    time.sleep(2)
NameError: name 'time' is not defined"
```

here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/q2v7sdbz

Any ideas towards what may be throwing this?

Best,

Jamie

Comment: You could have easily solved this with a basic google search.

Answer (score 2):

the `sleep` function comes from the python `time` module so you to `import` before you call any of it's methods 
just put

`import time`

before you use any time stuff. It's normal to just put all of your imports at the top of your code.

see here for more info on `import`ing:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the `time` module. Just write `import time` at the top of your file on its own line to import it.