# Error in Time Sleep

Tags: python

There is an error in this code...

```
time.sleep(5)
print ("Loading Successfull")`
```

When I run this code an error pops up it says:

```
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

I think I dont need to define time

I've recently have used this command it never said `TimeError` it's happening first time

```
print ("-----------------Welcome to Digits counter-----------------")#Welcomes the user
print ("")
print ("Loading...")
time.sleep (3)
print("Load Sucessfull")
```

Comment: Import the module `import time`

Comment: Like this? 
`import time`
`time.sleep (3)`

Comment: Now, simply "import time"

Comment: Cant wait to see the full "Digits counter" app up and running ;) Maybe you would want to reconsider a "loading" phase which does nothing except for sleeping.

Comment: @Merlin1896 for some reason young/new programmers love the idea of loading screens. It makes their app feel more special or like it's doing more or something. I think it's a phase we grow out of. :D

Comment: @DavidScherer True. I bet I would find similar lines in my old code.

Comment: @Merlin1896 I certainly could. There was time I spent more time making cool and unnecessary loaders than I did writing actual code. Now days we spend more time getting rid of loading and user wait times than we do writing actual code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.3.3 time.sleep() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616507/python-3-3-3-time-sleep-error)

Answer (score 3):

you need to import `time` module first.

```
import time

time.sleep(5)
```

Or instead of importing full `time` module, just import `sleep` from `time`:

```
from time import sleep
sleep(5)
```

rest of the code, remains same.